# The specified Store cannot be found

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I am in beginner level of Sencha touch. Right now, I am going through this [tutorial](http://miamicoder.com/2011/writing-a-sencha-touch-application-part-2/). Though this tutorial is old, till now I managed to sync with new methods of Sencha touch with the help of docs.

My problem is that I am getting a console error `[WARN][Ext.dataview.List#applyStore] The specified Store cannot be found` when I run my code in Chrome.

Expected result is that it will show a single list of data which is passing as store through `itmTpl` config.

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/2PBlo/)

I also tried solving it by creating `model` and `store` as

```
model --> NotesApp.model.Notes       (instead of "Notes")
store --> NotesApp.store.NotesStore  (instead of "NotesStore")
```

but no use. Still same error.

Comment: You need to define a `storeId` property for your store and mention the same for your list. That should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you following is old style and i suggest you to follow this [tutorial.](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/)

Same application but what you followed is not MVC and Tutorial i shared follows MVC, I followed this tutorial when i started sencha touch.

This application will be good start for you, Also i want to mention that this application is just a start not perfect.

As you learn more you will come to know best practice.

---

Having said that, lets solve the WARNING in that old code

You just defined the store, but NotesStore is not created and registered in Store Manager

[Ext.regStore(id,config)](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-regStore) will do that for you, Try this code.

```
Ext.application({
    name : ('SF' || 'SenchaFiddle'),
    launch : function() {
       Ext.define('Notes', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            id: 'modelId',
            config: {
                fields: [
                    { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
                    { name: 'date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' },
                    { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'narrative', type: 'string' }
                ],
                validations: [
                    { type: 'presence', field: 'id' },
                    { type: 'presence', field: 'title' }
                ]
            }
        });

      Ext.regStore('NotesStore', {
            require: 'Ext.data.Store',
            model: 'Notes',
            storeId : 'NotesStore',
            sorters: [{
                property: 'date',
                direction: 'DESC'
            }],
            proxy: {
                type: 'localstorage',
                id: 'notes-app-store'
            },
            // TODO: remove this data after testing.
            data: [
                { id: 1, date: new Date(), title: 'Test Note', narrative: 'This is simply a test note' }
            ]
        });


        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'card',
            html: "hello",
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                id: 'notesListContainer',
                layout: 'fit',
                html: 'This is the notes list container',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'top',
                    id: 'notesListToolbar',
                    title: 'My Notes'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    id: 'notesList',
                    //require: ['Notes.model.Notes','NotesApp.store.NotesStore'],
                    store: 'NotesStore',
                    itemTpl: '<div class="list-item-title">{title}</div>' +
                            '<div class="list-item-narrative">{narrative}</div>'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```